# print a single value from json array in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

iam new to angular2 my problem is iam having json object in that I have to print only the first id i.e. (expecting output Id=564) but iam getting all the id in my json.I searched a lot i didnt get a proper answer,help me to solve this problem.

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of roilist">
  <p >{{x[0].id}}</p></div>
```

```
{"items":[{"id":564,"sku":"MB570Z\/B","name":"Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter","attribute_set_id":4,"price":2800,"status":1,"visibility":4,"type_id":"simple","created_at":"2017-08-31 04:49:57","updated_at":"2017-08-31 05:06:31","weight":1,"extension_attributes":[],"product_links":[],"tier_prices":[],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"description","value":"Every Mac with a Mini DisplayPort allows you to connect an external display or projector using an adapter. You can use an external display as your main workspace or to extend your desktop, or you can work in mirrored mode with a projector so you can view what your audience sees.\r\nUse the Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter to connect an advanced digital monitor, such as the 20- or 23-inch Apple Cinema Display, that includes a DVI connector. Review the documentation or check with the manufacturer of your monitor to make sure you're choosing the right adapter."},{"attribute_code":"short_description","value":"Mini DisplayPort to DVI Adapter"},{"attribute_code":"image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"small_image","value":"\/a\/p\/apple_hdmi_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"thumbnail","value":"\/a\/p\/apple_hdmi_to_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"options_container","value":"container2"},{"attribute_code":"required_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"has_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"url_key","value":"mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter"},{"attribute_code":"msrp_display_actual_price_type","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"tax_class_id","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"gift_message_available","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"is_featured","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source","value":"28"},{"attribute_code":"hsncode","value":"85444299"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source_after_minprice","value":"-1"}]},{"id":565,"sku":"MB571Z\/A","name":"Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter","attribute_set_id":4,"price":9400,"status":1,"visibility":4,"type_id":"simple","created_at":"2017-08-31 04:49:58","updated_at":"2017-08-31 05:06:31","weight":1,"extension_attributes":[],"product_links":[],"tier_prices":[],"custom_attributes":[{"attribute_code":"description","value":"Every Mac with a Mini DisplayPort allows you to connect an external display or projector using an adaptor. You can use an external display as your main workspace or to extend your desktop, or you can work in mirrored mode with a projector so you can view what your audience sees.\nUse the Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adaptor to connect your Mac to a 30-inch display that includes a DVI connector, such as the 30-inch Apple Cinema Display HD, and enjoy the ultimate widescreen canvas with a resolution of 2560 by 1600 pixels."},{"attribute_code":"short_description","value":"Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter"},{"attribute_code":"image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"small_image","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"thumbnail","value":"\/m\/i\/mini_displayport_to_dual-link_dvi_adapter.jpg"},{"attribute_code":"options_container","value":"container2"},{"attribute_code":"required_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"has_options","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"url_key","value":"mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter"},{"attribute_code":"msrp_display_actual_price_type","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"tax_class_id","value":"2"},{"attribute_code":"gift_message_available","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"is_featured","value":"0"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source","value":"28"},{"attribute_code":"hsncode","value":"85444299"},{"attribute_code":"gst_source_after_minprice","value":"-1"}]}],"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[],"page_size":2},"total_count":92}
```

Comment: just a simple `{{roillist[0].id}}` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just do without ngFor

```
  <p >{{roilist[0].id}}</p></div>
```

Comment: Thank u, im getting single id value but it is repeating @Rahul.

Comment: you should not use ngFor

Comment: Get rid of the ngFor as suggested and the repetition will stop.